# Как собрать scala проект со swing в IntellijIdea?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, swing

Собственно, через sbt собирается.
build.sbt:

```
name := "test_sbt"

version := "1.0"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Main")

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.4"
```

В Idea тот же проект выдает ошибку:

> Error:(6, 14) object swing is not a member of package scala

на строке:

> import scala.swing._

Выдает ее и при запуске как Application, и при запуске как Console.
Как нужно сконфигурировать запуск, чтобы все заработало?

p.s. Настроила зависимости в проекте, заработало. Есть ли такая возможность, чтобы это прописывать нужно было только в одном месте для обоих вариантов? Где посмотреть, как делается Make?

upd: поставила плагин sbt, теперь сборка из консоли и IDE проходит одинаково.
Теперь падает, не находит класс

> scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce.

Ошибка NoClassDefFoundError ...

Caused by: ClassNotFoundException

Причем с "ранешней" сборкой через Idea без плагина такого не было.

Буду дальше искать. Код пока простой:

```
import scala.swing._

object Main extends SimpleSwingApplication{
  def top = new MainFrame{
  }
}
```

scala-library в classpath-е есть, нужный класс в jar-е тоже.

Comment: Какую версию идеи и scala плагина вы используете? До 13.x встроенный scala плагин не понимал sbt проекты и не мог подтягивать их зависимости (т.о. swing'а не было на classpath'е) и нужно было использовать другой плагин для регенерации проекта при каждом изменении сборочной инфы

Comment: @om-nom-nom Idea 13.1, только скачанная. Где можно версию плагина посмотреть? sbt-проект создавался в самой IDE.